# How to open a sub window with a simple Link

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to open with Vaadin a Sub Window with a simple Link. But the only thing a Link accepts is a URL, not a Window-Object. Is there a way to get the following code to work?

```
VerticalLayout ToDoList = new VerticalLayout();
ToDoList.setSpacing(true);
ToDoList.setMargin(true);
ToDoList.setSizeFull();
ToDoList.setSizeUndefined();

// ... 

Window mywindow = new Window("My Dialog");
mywindow.setPositionX(200);
mywindow.setPositionY(100);

ToDoList.addComponent(ToDoTable);
Link link = new Link("Click Me!", new ExternalResource(mywindow));
ToDoList.addComponent(link);
```

Comment: check out http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Open-Source-Library/Ajax/vaadin/com/vaadin/ui/Window.java.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
ToDoList.addComponent(ToDoTable);
Button link = new Button("Click Me!");
ToDoList.addComponent(link);
link.addClickListener(ClickListener()
  {
      onClick()
      {
          Window mywindow = new Window("My Dialog");
          mywindow.setPositionX(200);
          mywindow.setPositionY(100);
          mainwindow.addWindow(mywindow);
      }

  });
```

From here:

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.sub-window.html

if you wish to open a real browser window (not a sub window) then look here:

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.html

It then depends if the new window should be part of your vaadin app or just some other content or independent vaadin app instance.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually correct, but it would make the column unsortable. 
I solved the problem in a similar way with a Label and an additional column in the table.